# how to integration materialize js in vue and laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs2

I tried to require materialize in Vue and Laravel

in `bootstrap.js` I have

```
window.Materialize = require('materialize-css');
```

in `App.vue` component I have

```
mounted(){
  Materialize.toast('I am a toast!', 4000)
}
```

and received

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: Materialize is not defined"

message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either drop a script tag with materialize js or, make sure jquery is loaded before requiring materialize. 
I suppose you have a browserify setup and if you do you can do something like that:

```
require('jquery')(window);
require('materialize-css')(window);
```

Or something like that:

```
global.jQuery = require('jquery')
global.Materialize = require('materialize-css')
```

Or import globally jQuery only then simply `var Materialize=require('materialize-css')` and use the variabile instead.

For webpack setups add a plugin for the stuff you have installed via npm and need globally:

```
  plugins:[
   new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
   $: "jquery",
   jQuery:'jquery',
   jquery:'jquery'
 }),
],
```

Comment: i appreciate your kind support however the following code is the one worked with me 
`var Materialize=require('materialize-css')`