# Materialize js doesn't work on first load

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, materialize

I am trying to make a Vue.js SPA chat app and I have problem with Materialize CSS and JS. JS doesn't work on first load and to make it work I have to reload the page. Not sure where the problem is since there are no errors in the console.

Here is index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">

<title>Chat</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app"></div>
<!-- built files will be auto injected -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the component where is the problem:

```
 <template>
  <div class="container reg">
  <h1 class="text-centered">Registrace</h1>
 <form @submit.prevent="register">
   * Another form fields *
 <div class="input-field col s12">
  <select>
   <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
  </select>
  <label>Materialize Select</label>
 </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Registrovat" />
 </form>
 <router-link :to="{ name: 'login' }">
   <button>Login</button>
 </router-link>
</div>
</template>
<script>
 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var elems = document.querySelectorAll('select');
 var instances = M.FormSelect.init(elems, null);
  });
 export default {
    data: function () {
        return {

        };
    },
    methods: {
      Register () {
      }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems use an external jQuery library is an anti-pattern with Vue.js, because

> Vue.js and jquery fight over how the DOM is handled.

[See the last comment here](https://github.com/SimulatedGREG/electron-vue/issues/288)

I think you have to install it via `npm` and then insert manually the `css` and `js` in the compile process because I had the same problem with materialize and ionic 3.

- If you want to follow this way [this Answer can help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41965553/how-to-integration-materialize-js-in-vue-and-laravel)

If you wan't spend time finding a work-around way to import manually the `css` and `js` inside the compile process would be better to use a more Vue friendly solutions [like this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/)

I modified my answer to add another useful link. This library use the Materialize css  and Vue.js to build UI [appcomponents.org](http://appcomponents.org/material-components/#!/)

Comment: I've deleted jQuery lib. I didn't even realize it shouldn't be combined with Vue. The problem still persist tho. I would like to avoid changing CSS framework cause I would need to rewrite a lot of css and deadline is in few days. But thanks for advice.

Comment: @Alorain - See the last edit. I've added an answer with the work-around solution you are waiting for in the bullet list. As i supposed you have to add jQuery in the webpack process.

Comment: @Alorain - If you want i'll edit the answer to explain better this: If you only need the **Materialize** css files and not the js, you can simply add it in this way `var Materialize=require('materialize-css')`. But if you need all the javascript power of the **Materialize** library i suggest to use a pre built Vue.js library